# C forward declaration query

Tags: c

I have a situation where two of my header files require the data structures defined in either one, i.e. no matter which order you include them it won't compile

however, one of the problem data structures only contains *pointers* to the data structure declared in the other header file so I would have though that technically it doesn't need to know at this point how big the data structure is so it shouldn't be complaining

A simplified example of what I mean is outlined below. I would have thought that the array of modes in Library doesn't need to know how big a Mode is, only how big a pointer to a Mode is therefore the compiler shouldn't complain if it hasn't yet seen the declaration of Mode in the other header file.

```
header_1.h

typedef struct
{
    Mode **modes; 
} Library;

header_2.h

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char *name;
} Mode;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently written, your example does not show the mutual cross-referencing that you mention in the question.

The compiler must be told something about each type it uses.  You could use in `header_1.h` just:

```
typedef struct Mode Mode;

typedef struct
{
    Mode **modes; 
} Library;
```

That would make it compile, at least.  The compiler doesn't need the details, but it does need to know that `Modes` is a type.

*Edit:*
Note that `header_2.h` should be modified for this to work.  You have to ensure that each `typedef` appears just once.  After you have the typedefs in place, you specify the structure content (definition) once, and you omit the keyword `typedef` and the typedef name from the structure definition. And you have to decide on exactly the cross-references will be managed.  For example, should `header_1.h` include `header_2.h` anyway.

<s>I don't remember encountering a case where I really needed mutually referencing structures (in quite a long time programming — long enough that I could have forgotten a example).</s>  I do now remember a case of structures mutually referencing each other; it was in a version of `make` originally written for Minix.  I still regard such a requirement as somewhat 'pathological' (or, if you prefer, as a 'code smell') and as something to be avoided whenever possible.  If you really must manage it, then the section below explains how I'd go about doing it (and more or less how the `make` program did go about it).

### Mutually-referencing structures

If you truly have two mutually referencing structures, you should (re)consider why you think two headers are better than one.  If you still need two headers, you use an idiom like:

#### header_1.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_1_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_1_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef TYPEDEF_MODE
#define TYPEDEF_MODE
typedef struct Mode Mode;
#endif
#ifndef TYPEDEF_LIBRARY
#define TYPEDEF_LIBRARY
typedef struct Library Library;
#endif

struct Library
{
    ...
    Mode    **modes;
    ...
};

#endif /* HEADER_1_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### header_2.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_2_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_2_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef TYPEDEF_MODE
#define TYPEDEF_MODE
typedef struct Mode Mode;
#endif
#ifndef TYPEDEF_LIBRARY
#define TYPEDEF_LIBRARY
typedef struct Library Library;
#endif

struct Mode
{
    ...
    Library    **liblist;
    ...
};

#endif /* HEADER_2_H_INCLUDED */
```

The repeated `typedef` 'detection' code is not nice; a single header is better, in my estimation.  However, you can include `header_1.h` and `header_2.h` above in either order and it should compile.

Comment: re: your update - i think you've hit the nail on the head in as much as I need to rethink why I have two headers. It was originally to separate my new code from existing code but now I should probably merge the two as appropriate

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to know the size, but it must have seen a declaration. A forward declaration

```
typedef struct Mode Mode;
```

before the definition of `struct Library` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because "Mode" is a type defined using typedef and its not the name of the struct. You will either need to explicitly forward declare it or you can try using the code structured as follows:

```
header_1.h

typedef struct
{
    struct _Mode_t **modes; 
} Library;

header_2.h

typedef struct _Mode_t
{
    int number;
    char *name;
} Mode;
```

Comment: how would you explicitly forward declare it?